# Cobbler XMLRPC calls with PHP

Tags: php, xml-rpc, redhat

I'm new to xmlrpc and I've been trying to integrate with a cobbler server in order to pull some info out of it. Unfortunately, the documentation is at best, sparse so I need some help.

The xmlrpc info for cobbler is here

https://fedorahosted.org/cobbler/wiki/CobblerXmlrpc

using a process of elimnation, I've thrown together this test code in order to try pull some stuff.

```
<?php
include 'xmlrpc.inc';
// Make an object to represent our server.

$server = new xmlrpc_client('https://url/cobbler/cobbler_api'); 
$token = $server->login("username","password");   
echo $server->getprofiles("name");   
?>
```

I get precisely nothing. So, what have I done wrong? How can i check the request is actually being performed correctly.

obviously I've replaced `url` `username` and `password` for the purposes of this question

Comment: What's in `xmlrpc.inc`?  Do you have `error_reporting` turned all the way up?  (Also, you probably shouldn't be using the PHP3-era .inc naming scheme any longer, it's really easy to accidentally expose a security issue.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled XMLRPC access in cobbler? I found the following in their documentation:

> This disables all external XMLRPC
>   modifications, and also disables the
>   Cobbler Web interface. Use this if you
>   do not want to allow any external
>   access and do not want to use the web
>   interface. This is the default setting
>   in Cobbler for new installations

Have a look [here](https://fedorahosted.org/cobbler/wiki/CustomizableSecurity) on how to enable XMLRPC on your server

Comment: Yep, the default Python example works so XMLRPC is definitely enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have fixed this myself.

I used Intutio's XMLRPC library and it worked like a charm, made it much easier once I'd included that.